# Custom wodpress dashboard widget with dismissible notices

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I'm trying to build a custom wodpress dashboard widget with dismissible notices, but something is not working. I tried to use these WP `classes` **"notice"**, **"notice-success"**, **"error"**, **"is-dismissible"**, but this isn't functioning.

Is this possible?

**This is my code:**

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'my_admin_dashboard_widget' );
function my_admin_dashboard_widget() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget( '', __( 'Alerts', 'text-domain' ), 'my_dashboard_admin_widget_handler' );
}

function my_dashboard_admin_widget_handler() {
    echo '<div class="start-stylling-my-widget">';

    _e( 'Here I put some text.', 'text-domain' );

// I tried to use these WP classes on div's: "notice", "notice-success", "error", "is-dismissible", but this isn't working 
    echo '<div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">';
    echo '<p>' . _e( 'Done!', 'text-domain' ) . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="notice error is-dismissible" >';
    echo '<p>' . _e( 'Install it now!', 'text-domain' ) . '</p>
    </div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: The dashboard doesn't use dismissible things, I don't think, I think only [admin notices](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_notices/). If you want to have something dismissible in that area, you will have to handle that yourself.

Comment: On a semi-related note, WordPress is making admin notices in general better with 6.4 which will be released soon, it may or may not be helpful to poke through that to see if anything is relevant to you. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/10/16/introducing-admin-notice-functions-in-wordpress-6-4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wordpress dashboard widgets does not automatically support the dismissible notices functionality that you see in the admin pages. The classes "`notice", "notice-success", "error", "is-dismissible"` are used for admin notices, and the JavaScript that makes them dismissible is not enqueued on the dashboard widget pages by default.

I hope the following helps

```
   <?php
    // Enqueue the JavaScript needed to make the notices dismissible
    function my_enqueue_dashboard_scripts() {
        if (is_admin()) {
            wp_enqueue_script('dashboard');
        }
    }
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_dashboard_scripts');
    
    add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'my_admin_dashboard_widget');
    function my_admin_dashboard_widget() {
        wp_add_dashboard_widget('', __('Alerts', 'text-domain'), 'my_dashboard_admin_widget_handler');
    }
    
    // Widget content handler
    function my_dashboard_admin_widget_handler() {
        echo '<div class="start-stylling-my-widget">';
    
        _e('Here I put some text.', 'text-domain');
    
        echo '<div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible" data-notice="my_custom_notice">';
        echo '<p>' . __('Done!', 'text-domain') . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    
        echo '</div>';
    

        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(document).on('click', '.notice.is-dismissible', function() {
                              $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```